# Do latched publishers work with mux?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does a publisher being latched interfere with the operation of the mux topic_tool? See my last question and the helpful comment by gvdhoom (http://answers.ros.org/question/326929/use-topic_tools-mux-to-load-multiple-maps/).

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326939/do-latched-publishers-work-with-mux?/) by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 977 on 2019-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, and I haven't tested this myself, but a latched publisher only sends the last message to any subscriber. If the `mux` subscribes to all it's inputs when it's started (edit: [seems like it does](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/29053c4832229efa7160fb944c05e3bc82e11540/tools/topic_tools/src/mux.cpp#L313-L321)), it will receive those messages. But, as typically only a single topic is selected as the initial input, all the other messages on the other inputs will be "lost" (not really, but as those inputs are not active, `mux` will not forward them).

Now you can switch to other inputs, but since the latched publisher has already sent its one-and-only message, the `mux` will not see any new msgs and so will not forward them.

Again: I don't know whether this is what actually happens, but it seems a logical explanation of what you are seeing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2019-06-26**:
Yes that is the conclusion I am coming to, thank you very much!